# SOAP XML function call with multiple parameters

Tags: php, xml, soap-client

Dear Stackoverflowers,

Is it possible to do the following?

```
$client = new SoapClient("wsdldocument.wsdl");
$result = $client->myFunction( $param1, $param2, $param3 );
```

(How) Can I pass multiple arguments to a call?

I have already tried the following, but this also didn't work for me:

```
$client = new SoapClient("wsdldocument.swdl");
$params = array( "param1" => $param1, "param2" => $param2, "param3" => $param3 );
$result = $client->__soapCall( "myFunction", $params );
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Comment: Thank you for your reaction Hakre, but i have already tried this. Somehow only the first parameter get's through. I will edit my post to show you what i've also tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working :)

The WSDL file had been cached and changed afterwards.
The following code helped me out:

```
ini_set( "soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0 );
```